# How to ensure a React component has 'key' prop in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I type a typescript variable so that it requires a component with the `key` set?

I want something like this:

```js
const foo: ReactElementWithKey = <div key="some key"></div> 
// all ok

const bar: ReactElementWithKey = <div></div> 
// no `key` - typescript should show an error
```

How should I define the `ReactElementWithKey` ?

I have tried something like:

```js
type ReactElementWithKey = React.ReactElement<{ key: React.Key }>;
```

But it doesn't work - components with no `key` are accepted just fine.

Comment: key is reserved, you shouldn't be able to type it, instead enforce it with eslint

Comment: you can't with typescript, but you can add a Fragment with key wrapping your var usage. It's even better from a Separation of Concern standpoint if you think about it

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to use a custom version of the `<div>` component, like this:

```
import React from 'react';

// required non-null key prop
interface WithKeyProps {
    key: React.Key;
}

// custom div wrapper
const DivWithKey = (props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & WithKeyProps) => {
    return (
        <div {...props}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}

const foo = <DivWithKey key='' />;
// all ok
const bar = <DivWithKey />;
// no `key` - typescript shows an error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeiriIEcBXYIgEzgDsIOBaDxgDYC4AayQBPOGBxhywDjCRRM6JHADqwGAAsA0hIAKMgM5wA3uThXREgFyJiMAHT7xFAL6UacNI2MxcOFZgADc4AHcoFDAwJXI0bn84ABFQzR1XOABeOAAKaQgwY3tkdGcACQAVAFkAGQBBGBgoYAAjRkVjAB4qutSQgFEBJBAkBQA+OAAyDS09QxMASmzJi2s6JBhGKA48y3XrLuCwsyczgqL3cf2Dg7ML4yc0bWABViIOT1urLqpj6-Wiw8lASHCSmAgEGycC6-XS80kYnEWXw+DgVHGFG8KCEcAgIniiXgrRQUGhsLSc0yGKxtC4cAABkiGXAeHAYOJYsY0C0wPBjNoIOFTChdkocFAgA)

The problem is that this is only for `<div>`s, so this might not quite do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

`key` is a value that we can pass to any component to help react with the rendering logic. You might have seen key used as part of looping logic. Similar to that, any component can have a property `key` which will force the component to re-render when the `key` changes. In other words, it's reserved for react. I suggest to use some other name if your purpose is different.

This is how I am defining a type in my typescript react project.

```
interface ITestComponentProps {//your prop types here}

const TestComponent: React.FC<ITestComponentProps> = (props) => {
  return <>Some JSX</>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

First, all rendered react components are just the `JSX.Element` type. All type information about what was rendered is lost when rendered. So you cannot type a variable to only accept some rendered react components.

Second, `key` [is a reserved prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) by React. Every component optionally accepts it.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but there is probably a better way.