# How can I use TypeScript to require a key for React props.children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've created an interface that extends `JSX.Element` and am trying to use it to type `props.children`. The idea is that, yes you can pass an array of elements as children to this component, but they have to have a `key` property. The component should be flexible enough to accept any JSX at all, as long as the key is not null.

PickyWrapper.tsx:

```
export interface ElementWithKey extends JSX.Element {
  key: React.Key;
}

interface Props {
  children: ElementWithKey[];
}

export const PickyWrapper: (props: Props) => JSX.Element = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

export default PickyWrapper;
```

App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
        <PickyWrapper>
           <div key="mykey">Example 1</div>   // Should pass type checking
           <div>Example 2</div>               // Should throw a TS error
        </PickyWrapper>
     </div>
  );
 }
```

(CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-williamson-i183k?file=/src/PickyWrapper.tsx)

This doesn't compile, because "Element is not assignable to type ElementWithKey" (even when the key is defined).

There are obviously workarounds here (type assertions, for example, or using a different prop name than `children`), but overriding the default type for `children` is a pretty normal pattern and it would be nice to use the familiar `<Component><Child /><Child /></Component>` syntax for this case as well (without having every consumer have to cast `as ElementWithKey` each time). Is it possible?

Comment: isn't `react` already provide `warning` for `key` on `list` item

Answer (score 1):

**Hi dev**

I was looking for smth like this too. Seems more complex that its appear.

Maybe could be related to "key" being a reserved prop. (Related answer: [How to ensure a React component has 'key' prop in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091435/how-to-ensure-a-react-component-has-key-prop-in-typescript))

I need this to ensure the children elements of my list component has a unique key to assign it to each list item. I use this FC to not repeat the same list item elements when need to iterate.

```
import type { FC } from 'react'

const List: FC<ListProps> = ({ tag = 'ul', children, itemClassName, listClassName }) => {
  const ListTag = tag as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  const ItemTag = (tag === 'div' ? 'div' : 'li') as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  return (
    <ListTag
      className={`flex list-none flex-wrap items-start justify-start ${listClassName ?? ''}`}
    >
      {(Array.isArray(children) ? children : [children]).map((child, index) => (
        <ItemTag key={child.key ?? index} className={`block ${itemClassName ?? ''}`}>
          {child}
        </ItemTag>
      ))}
    </ListTag>
  )
}

type ListProps = {
  tag?: 'ol' | 'ul' | 'div'
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
  itemClassName?: string
  listClassName?: string
}

export default List
export type { ListProps }
```

But as you pointed out. Key isn't a required prop. I also tried like you did to create a custom type using JSX.Element.

```
type ListItem = JSX.Element & {
  listKey: string | number
}
```

But even using a different prop name (as you can see) this gives the same error as you:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ListItem'
```

For now my best solution is to keeps the keys optional. Or I also could create a prop called items instead of children and specify custom props on it.

Let me know please if you found a solution to this. Maybe on newer version of TS.

**Happy coding dev**